# Painting a point in drawing area in gtkmm

Tags: cairo, gtkmm, drawingarea

I have created a drawing area using the following code in gtkmm:

```
bool DrawingArea::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
{
cr->set_source_rgb(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);   // white background
cr->paint();
cr->move_to(0,0);
cr->line_to(10,10);
cr->line_to(20,20);
return true;
}
```

The code paints lines in the drawing area.

I want to draw a point in this area after calling a function that paints the point. I want to repaint in the same context. I did it like:

```
void DrawingArea::on_point()
{
  cr->arc(10.0,10.0,1.0,1.0, 2 * M_PI);
  cr->set_source_rgba(0.0,0.0,0.8,0.6);
  cr->fill_preserve();
  cr->stroke();
}
```

The above function is called on clicking menu item. queue_draw() function in gtkmm can be used. How do I use it to repaint in the drawing area?

Any help shall be really appreciated!